# Postgres OleDb provider for linux

Tags: database, postgresql, oledb, provider

I want to use OleDB to access PostgreSQL database on Linux. I want to know is it possible? If yes from where "Postgres OleDb provider for Linux" can be downloaded.

Thanks in advance,
Vijay Kumar Singh
EDISPHERE Software

Answer (score 0):

How about looking at http://www.pgoledb.com/? Do note that OLEDB is on the way out and you are probably better off with some other solution that has a clear future.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The website  http://www.pgoledb.com/ is talking about  the PGNP provider is a thin layer between Microsoft ADO and PostgreSQL database. I am looking for Postgres oledb provider for Linux.

Comment: OLEDB is a Microsoft product and most definitely not available for Linux.